# Is there a function for checking if an action map key was pressed in Unreal?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

[image: wasInputKeyJustPressed]

So inside the player controller there is a nice function called `WasInputKeyJustPressed`, you give it a `key` and it outputs a `bool`. I was curious if there was a similar function for Action Keys. For example, if I had an action mapping called `MyActionKey` which was tied to the Space bar. Is there a function like `WasActionKeyJustPressed` that essentially does the same thing as the original? If not how can I detect that with my player controller in a similar manner to `WasInputKeyJustPressed`?

I am not interested with the `InputAction MyActionKey` for this case it does not work for me. I am really looking for a function that will just output whether or not that particular Action Key is pressed in a `bool` form.

If this is a custom function that needs to be written then it would be nice if say I could pass in the name of the Action Key. **I'd prefer if the solution was in C++.**

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a sort of work around. Essentially, you can grab the input settings and then from there grab your axis mappings or your action mappings. They are both very similar. From there I looped through each of the mappings and grabbed the key it was referencing and called the `WasInputKeyJustPressed` function. An example below:

```
TArray<FInputAxisKeyMapping> axisMapping;
UInputSettings::GetInputSettings()->GetAxisMappingByName(axisName, axisMapping);
for(auto axis : axisMapping)
{
    if (playerController->WasInputKeyJustPressed(axis.Key))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```